# Hierarchial Edge Bundling: adding parent group label

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dendrogram

I'm quite new to HTML and JavaScript. I'm facing the famous Hierarchical Edge Bundling available [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999), which is generated by the D3.js library.

My goal is to add a semi-circular label zone in order to obtain something like this: every final node group is labelled with the parent's name.
[image]

Unfortunately, I have not found any code where I could take inspiration yet, except the code available in the link above: my idea would be to modify that code adding some line in order to generate the labels.

I saw this [link](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339607) with a snippet of code that may do to the trick, but I don't know how to use it (and whether I am in the right direction or not)

```
node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".31em")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x < 180 === !d.children ? 6 : -6; })
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 === !d.children ? "start" : "end"; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x < 180 ? d.x - 90 : d.x + 90) + ")"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); });
```

Does someone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is to draw a series of arcs around the links and shunt the labels outwards by the width of the arc.

### V4 solution

A working adaption of the d3 v4 code from the [linked block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999) is below:

```js
var flare = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/robinmackenzie/d01d286d9ac16b474a2a43088c137d00/raw/c53c1eda18cc21636ae52dfffa3e030295916c98/flare.json";
d3.json(flare, function(err, json) {
  if (err) throw err;
  render(json);
});

function render(classes) {
  
  // original code
  var diameter = 960,
      radius = diameter / 2,
      innerRadius = radius - 120;

  var cluster = d3.cluster()
      .size([360, innerRadius]);

  var line = d3.radialLine()
      .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
      .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
      .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", diameter)
      .attr("height", diameter)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

  var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
      node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

  var root = packageHierarchy(classes)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; });

  cluster(root);
  
  // added code -----
  var arcInnerRadius = innerRadius;
  var arcWidth = 30;
  var arcOuterRadius = arcInnerRadius + arcWidth;
  
  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(arcInnerRadius)
    .outerRadius(arcOuterRadius)
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.st; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.et; });
    
  var leafGroups = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.parent.data.name.split(".")[1]; })
    .entries(root.leaves())
    
  var arcAngles = leafGroups.map(function(group) {
    return {
      name: group.key,
      min: d3.min(group.values, function(d) { return d.x }),
      max: d3.max(group.values, function(d) { return d.x })
    }
  });
    
  svg
    .selectAll(".groupArc")
    .data(arcAngles)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return`arc_${i}`; })
    .attr("d", function(d) { return arc({ st: d.min * Math.PI / 180, et: d.max * Math.PI / 180}) }) // note use of arcWidth
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");
    
  svg
    .selectAll(".arcLabel")
    .data(arcAngles)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 5) //Move the text from the start angle of the arc
    .attr("dy", (d) => ((arcOuterRadius - arcInnerRadius) * 0.8)) //Move the text down
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("class", "arcLabel")
    .attr("xlink:href", (d, i) => `#arc_${i}`)
    .text((d, i) => d.name)
    .style("font", `300 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`)
    .style("fill", "#fff");

  // ----------------

  link = link
    .data(packageImports(root.leaves()))
    .enter().append("path")
      .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", line);

  node = node
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8 + arcWidth) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; })
      .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
      .on("mouseout", mouseouted);

  function mouseovered(d) {
    node
        .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });

    link
        .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
        .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
      .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
        .raise();

    node
        .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
        .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });
  }

  function mouseouted(d) {
    link
        .classed("link--target", false)
        .classed("link--source", false);

    node
        .classed("node--target", false)
        .classed("node--source", false);
  }

  // Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
  function packageHierarchy(classes) {
    var map = {};

    function find(name, data) {
      var node = map[name], i;
      if (!node) {
        node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
        if (name.length) {
          node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
          node.parent.children.push(node);
          node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
        }
      }
      return node;
    }

    classes.forEach(function(d) {
      find(d.name, d);
    });

    return d3.hierarchy(map[""]);
  }

  // Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
  function packageImports(nodes) {
    var map = {},
        imports = [];

    // Compute a map from name to node.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      map[d.data.name] = d;
    });

    // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      if (d.data.imports) d.data.imports.forEach(function(i) {
        imports.push(map[d.data.name].path(map[i]));
      });
    });

    return imports;
  }


}
```

```css
.node {
  font: 300 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  fill: #bbb;
}

.node:hover {
  fill: #000;
}

.link {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-opacity: 0.4;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.node:hover,
.node--source,
.node--target {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.node--source {
  fill: #2ca02c;
}

.node--target {
  fill: #d62728;
}

.link--source,
.link--target {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link--source {
  stroke: #d62728;
}

.link--target {
  stroke: #2ca02c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You can see the discrete block of code added to draw and label the arcs - the key bit to calculate the start and end angles for the arc generator are:

```
  var leafGroups = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.parent.data.name.split(".")[1]; })
    .entries(root.leaves())
    
  var arcAngles = leafGroups.map(function(group) {
    return {
      name: group.key,
      min: d3.min(group.values, function(d) { return d.x }),
      max: d3.max(group.values, function(d) { return d.x })
    }
  });
```

For `leafGroups`, the nest function is grouping the leaves of the hierarchy by the second item of the key e.g. `flare.analytics.cluster` = `analytics` and `flare.vis.operator.distortion` = `vis`. There is a choice here for different data sets that you need to have a think about e.g. if the leaves are always at a consistent depth; are the labels always unique. Defining the 'parent group' can either be a top-down or bottom-up definition.

For `arcAngles`, you just need the min and max of each group then you can go ahead and draw the arcs and label them. I lifted some of the labelling from [here](https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/09/placing-text-on-arcs/) which is a great article on labelling arcs in d3. You need to have a think, again, for this bit because if the label is too long for the arc it doesn't look great - see the "Display" label in the example.

The other change is further down here:

```
  node = node
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8 + arcWidth) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; })
      .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
      .on("mouseout", mouseouted);
```

Noting you need to add `arcWidth` when setting the `transform` attribute - this moves the node labels outward to accommodate the arcs.

### V6+ solution

There's a newer version of hierarchical edge bundling in this [Observable HQ](https://observablehq.com/@d3/hierarchical-edge-bundling) page using d3 v6 (and also by Mike Bostok). We can add similar code to identify groups, get the min/ max of the angles and push the labels outward a bit to accomodate the arcs.

```js
const flare = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/robinmackenzie/d01d286d9ac16b474a2a43088c137d00/raw/c53c1eda18cc21636ae52dfffa3e030295916c98/flare.json";
const colorin = "#00f";
const colorout = "#f00";
const colornone = "#ccc";
const width = 960;
const radius = width / 2;

d3.json(flare).then(json => render(json));

function render(data) {

  const line = d3.lineRadial()
    .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
    .radius(d => d.y)
    .angle(d => d.x);

  const tree = d3.cluster()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius - 100]);

  const root = tree(bilink(d3.hierarchy(hierarchy(data))
    .sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.height, b.height) || d3.ascending(a.data.name, b.data.name))));

  const svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", width)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${radius},${radius})`);

  // NEW CODE BELOW ----------------------------------------
  // add arcs with labels
  const arcInnerRadius = radius - 100;
  const arcWidth = 30;
  const arcOuterRadius = arcInnerRadius + arcWidth;
  const arc = d3
    .arc()
    .innerRadius(arcInnerRadius)
    .outerRadius(arcOuterRadius)
    .startAngle((d) => d.start)
    .endAngle((d) => d.end);

  const leafGroups = d3.groups(root.leaves(), d => d.parent.data.name);
  const arcAngles = leafGroups.map(g => ({
    name: g[0],
    start: d3.min(g[1], d => d.x),
    end: d3.max(g[1], d => d.x)
  }));

  svg
    .selectAll(".arc")
    .data(arcAngles)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("id", (d, i) => `arc_${i}`)
    .attr("d", (d) => arc({start: d.start, end: d.end}))
    .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("stroke", "blue");
  svg
    .selectAll(".arcLabel")
    .data(arcAngles) 
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 5) //Move the text from the start angle of the arc
    .attr("dy", (d) => ((arcOuterRadius - arcInnerRadius) * 0.8)) //Move the text down
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("class", "arcLabel")
    .attr("xlink:href", (d, i) => `#arc_${i}`)
    .text((d, i) => ((d.end - d.start) < (6 * Math.PI / 180)) ? "" : d.name); // 6 degrees min arc length for label to apply
    
  // --------------------------------------------------------



  // add nodes
  const node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .join("g")
      .attr("transform", d => `rotate(${d.x * 180 / Math.PI - 90}) translate(${d.y}, 0)`)
    .append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("x", d => d.x < Math.PI ? (arcWidth + 5) : (arcWidth + 5) * -1) // note use of arcWidth
      .attr("text-anchor", d => d.x < Math.PI ? "start" : "end")
      .attr("transform", d => d.x >= Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : null)
      .text(d => d.data.name)
      .each(function(d) { d.text = this; })
      .on("mouseover", overed)
      .on("mouseout", outed)
      .call(text => text.append("title").text(d => `${id(d)} ${d.outgoing.length} outgoing ${d.incoming.length} incoming`));

  // add edges
  const link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", colornone)
      .attr("fill", "none")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(root.leaves().flatMap(leaf => leaf.outgoing))
    .join("path")
      .style("mix-blend-mode", "multiply")
      .attr("d", ([i, o]) => line(i.path(o)))
      .each(function(d) { d.path = this; });

  function overed(event, d) {
    link.style("mix-blend-mode", null);
    d3.select(this).attr("font-weight", "bold");
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", colorin).raise();
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(([d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", colorin).attr("font-weight", "bold");
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", colorout).raise();
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(([, d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", colorout).attr("font-weight", "bold");
  }

  function outed(event, d) {
    link.style("mix-blend-mode", "multiply");
    d3.select(this).attr("font-weight", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(([d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", null).attr("font-weight", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(([, d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", null).attr("font-weight", null);
  }  

  function id(node) {
    return `${node.parent ? id(node.parent) + "." : ""}${node.data.name}`;
  }

  function bilink(root) {
    const map = new Map(root.leaves().map(d => [id(d), d]));
    for (const d of root.leaves()) d.incoming = [], d.outgoing = d.data.imports.map(i => [d, map.get(i)]);
    for (const d of root.leaves()) for (const o of d.outgoing) o[1].incoming.push(o);
    return root;
  }

  function hierarchy(data, delimiter = ".") {
    let root;
    const map = new Map;
    data.forEach(function find(data) {
      const {name} = data;
      if (map.has(name)) return map.get(name);
      const i = name.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
      map.set(name, data);
      if (i >= 0) {
        find({name: name.substring(0, i), children: []}).children.push(data);
        data.name = name.substring(i + 1);
      } else {
        root = data;
      }
      return data;
    });
    return root;
  }
  
}
```

```css
.node {
  font: 300 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  fill: #fff;
}

.arcLabel {
  font: 300 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  fill: #fff;
}

.node:hover {
  fill: #000;
}

.link {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-opacity: 0.4;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.node:hover,
.node--source,
.node--target {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.node--source {
  fill: #2ca02c;
}

.node--target {
  fill: #d62728;
}

.link--source,
.link--target {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link--source {
  stroke: #d62728;
}

.link--target {
  stroke: #2ca02c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Some differences to note:

- The `hierarchy` function differs from the `packageHierarchy` function in the original block - seemingly we no longer have the full path of the hierarchy and therefore there's ambiguity for `flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite` vs `flare.data.DataField` i.e. two leaves can have the same 'parent' in different branches of the hierarchy.
- I've fixed the input to accomodate that but it changes how the 'parent group' is identified i.e. bottom-up vs top-down in the original.
- `nest` has gone so you can use `groups` instead
- The v4 seems to have objects defined with angles in degrees, but in v6 they are in radians - so you will see a few `* Math.PI / 180` in the v4 version and not in the v6 - but it's just degrees/ radians conversion.
- for long labels, I use a threshold such that an arc has to be minimum 6 degrees long otherwise the label won't place (`.text((d, i) => ((d.end - d.start) < (6 * Math.PI / 180)) ? "" : d.name);`)